# How to build Emacs from sources on Termux

Tags: android, termux

Background: [Termux](https://termux.com) is a Linux terminal environment that runs under Android. It provides a terminal version of Emacs 25.3.

However, I would like to build Emacs directly from the `master` branch in the archive. However, I have stumbled on two problems:

1) The [emacs build recipe](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/emacs) for termux patches a number of files. I will need to apply those patches as well.

2) When running `autoconf.sh` (to generate the `configure` script), I get a number of errors. (I can't copy-paste from the android device, unfortunately). When running `autoreconf -fi -I m4` the following is emitted:

```
/PATH/TO/bin/m4: m4_syscmd subprocess failed
configure.ac:5191: error: expected source file, required through AC_LIBSOURCES, not found
m4/gnulib-comp.m4:177:gl_INIT is expanded from...
configure.ac:5191: the top level
autom4te: /PATH/TO/bin/m4 failed with exit status 1
...
```

Does anybody has a step by step description on how to build Emacs from source on Termux? Alternatively, do you have any suggestion on how I should modify the build scripts myself so that they get the latest version rather than a specific one? (The build scripts downloads the sources as a `tar.gz` file, presumably with a pre-generated `configure` file, so a great help would be if someone would provide the latest sources the same way.)

Answer (score 1):

Latest source tarball is available from

https://hydra.nixos.org/job/gnu/emacs-trunk/tarball/latest

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I need! I'll try to build Emacs on termux and get back with a full recipe.